# Visual Studio Code: Paperscript

Tags: visual-studio-code, paperjs

(sorry for my english skills) Did you know any ext or something to color paperscript code?

[paperscript off colors example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21ZGS.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your editor doesn't recognise the `text/paperscript` MIMEtype, it doesn't know what syntax highlighting to apply to it.

To circumvent this, your best bet is to store your paperscript code in a separate file with the `.js` extension. Then your editor will automatically apply the correct JS syntax highlighting to it.

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas" src="index.js"></script>
```

**index.js**

```
// exactly the same code you had inline before
for (var x = 0; x < 1000; x += 100) {

    for (var y = 0; y < 1000; y += 100) {

        var myCircle = new Path.Circle(new Point(x, y), 10);
        myCircle.fillColor = 'purple';

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A similar issue re text/babel was raised here : https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/11781

What you have to do is find the default VSCode `html.json` file and make a small edit

On Windows it will be something like this : `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\html\syntaxes\html.json`

On Mac you have to find the VSCode app in your Applications folder and right click 'Show package contents' and nav to `/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/html/syntaxes/html.json`

You should find a codeblock like this (search for `javascript`)

```js
{
  "begin": "\\G",
  "end": "(?i:(?=/?>|type(?=[\\s=])(?!\\s*=\\s*('|\"|)(text/(javascript|ecmascript|babel)|application/((x-)?javascript|ecmascript|babel)|module)[\\s\"'>])))",
  "name": "meta.tag.metadata.script.html",
  "patterns": [
    {
      "include": "#tag-stuff"
    }
  ]
},
```

just add paperscript to the regex like this

```js
{
  "begin": "\\G",
  "end": "(?i:(?=/?>|type(?=[\\s=])(?!\\s*=\\s*('|\"|)(text/(javascript|ecmascript|babel|paperscript)|application/((x-)?javascript|ecmascript|babel|paperscript)|module)[\\s\"'>])))",
  "name": "meta.tag.metadata.script.html",
  "patterns": [
    {
      "include": "#tag-stuff"
    }
  ]
},
```

save the html.json and restart VSCode and you should be good to go.

I have raised a request at https://github.com/textmate/html.tmbundle/issues to have this included by default

Comment: Here is the video for the same: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-mHkmAZBkzo

Comment: Thanks, I made changes to the 'html.json' file, and restarted vscode and it worked. Although I found the file in a different directory from the one posted here.
This is where I found mine "C:\Users\MY PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\html\syntaxes\html.tmLanguage.json".

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't found that the problem has yet been fixed and had to fix it myself manually as well.

Just wanted to bring up the way to fix this quickly on Windows 10 now that they use a user specific installation.

The directory you are searching for now is a little tougher to find. You are looking for `C:\Users\{user name here}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\html\syntaxes\` and then the file is named `html.tmLanguage.json` instead. Otherwise the solution is still similar, search for the first instance of javascript and include paperscript in the regex for it. For me I found this long line.

```
"end": "(?ix:\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(?=>\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t# Tag without type attribute\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | type(?=[\\s=])\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  \t(?!\\s*=\\s*\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t''\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t# Empty\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | \"\"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#   Values\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | ('|\"|)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\ttext/\t\t\t\t\t\t\t# Text mime-types\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tjavascript(1\\.[0-5])?\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | x-javascript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | jscript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | livescript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | (x-)?ecmascript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | babel\t\t\t\t\t\t# Javascript variant currently\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#   recognized as such\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t   \t)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | application/\t\t\t\t\t# Application mime-types\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  \t(\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(x-)?javascript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | (x-)?ecmascript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | module\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  \t)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t[\\s\"'>]\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t)",
```

And changed it to this long line

```
"end": "(?ix:\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(?=>\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t# Tag without type attribute\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | type(?=[\\s=])\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  \t(?!\\s*=\\s*\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t''\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t# Empty\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | \"\"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#   Values\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | ('|\"|)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\ttext/\t\t\t\t\t\t\t# Text mime-types\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tjavascript(1\\.[0-5])?\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | x-javascript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | jscript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | livescript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | (x-)?ecmascript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | babel\t\t\t\t\t\t# Javascript variant currently\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#   recognized as such\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t       | paperscript\t\t\t\t\t\t# Javascript variant currently\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#   recognized as such\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  \t)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | application/\t\t\t\t\t# Application mime-types\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  \t(\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(x-)?javascript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | (x-)?ecmascript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | module\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  \t)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t[\\s\"'>]\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t)",
```

I would recommend turning on line wrapping while reading through the document, and just add in `| paperscript` where possible. Microsoft VS Code doesn't seem to have added any support for this mimetype, but this is the quick and dirty way to solve it when you want to use the paperscript syntax in the HTML itself.

Comment: I didn't find the file where you mentioned, but I did find it in the installation directory, I changed the way you said and restarted the visual studio, but it did not work for me, can you point to the alternative approach if you know one?

Answer (score 1):

Its been a little bit tricky to find the relevant path, so for the new users this is the solution:

the standard path of the installed VS is :

```
C:\Users\yourusername -> then you need to enter AppData, as default you can't see the folder so you need to go to the windows ribbon and click view -> show hidden.
```

then you can easily go the the next path:

```
C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\html\syntaxes\html.tmLanguage.json
```

open with you vs and search for the first javascript appearance.
the copy this to the right (with | between them) and change it from x-javascript to paperscript.

It should help you solve the issue.