# Is there a way to add PaperJS syntax highlighting to VSCode?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, paperjs

I'm working on project that implements PaperJS library and I want to add syntax highlighting. From my understanding, I need to modify the ***html.json*** file of VSCode located in the following path: 
`C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\html\syntaxes`

When I went to that folder, two different JSON files were there: ***html.tmLanguage*** and ***html-derivative.tmLanguage***. I checked out the initial file and found what seemed to be the right place to edit the code according to Perry Dyball answer in this question thread: [Visual Studio Code: Paperscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44256968/visual-studio-code-paperscript).

However, the lines of code to edit are full of `\t`:

[image: backslash t issue]

I expected to be able to add syntax highlighting for PaperJS by modify this JSON file according to Perry Dyball's answer for the question thread mentioned in this post, but I am conflicted on the way to do that and there seems to be no answer online for the different file names or the lines full of `\t`.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue but I got it running by simply adding `| paperscript |` **twice** before the `(x-)?ecmascript`so it will look like this:
[html.tmLanguage.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAYPG.png)
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me too. I added:

```
| paperscript || paperscript |
```

before the ***first*** instance of `(x-)?ecmascript` in html.tmLanguage.json