# Where is the default html.json file for syntax highlighting in Visual Studio Code on Linux?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to enable paperscript syntax highlighting in HTML files in visual studio code.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work by default, but there is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44256968/visual-studio-code-paperscript) that seems like it should work. I can't find the relevent file on arch linux.

Doing a `find` on the root for the folder "syntaxes" pointed me to `/usr/lib/code/extensions/html/...` which *seems* to be what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, the actual file is `html.tmLanguage.json` instead of `html.json`, and is unreadable.

I'm desperate at this point, just want syntax highlighting for paperscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is just minified json. You can beautify it by running it through a [beautifier](https://codebeautify.org/jsonminifier) (click beautify) and then copy the beautified version back in. It's still interpreted the same because it's still valid json.

Now, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56267906/3421994):

Search for the first instance of `javascript` which will take you to this line:

```
"end": "(?ix:\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(?=>\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t# Tag without type attribute\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | type(?=[\\s=])\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  \t(?!\\s*=\\s*\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t''\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t# Empty\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | \"\"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#   Values\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | ('|\"|)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\ttext/\t\t\t\t\t\t\t# Text mime-types\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tjavascript(1\\.[0-5])?\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | x-javascript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | jscript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | livescript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | (x-)?ecmascript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | babel\t\t\t\t\t\t# Javascript variant currently\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#   recognized as such\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t   \t)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | application/\t\t\t\t\t# Application mime-types\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  \t(\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(x-)?javascript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | (x-)?ecmascript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | module\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  \t)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t[\\s\"'>]\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t)",
```

and replace it with:

```
"end": "(?ix:\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(?=>\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t# Tag without type attribute\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | type(?=[\\s=])\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  \t(?!\\s*=\\s*\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t''\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t# Empty\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | \"\"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#   Values\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | ('|\"|)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\ttext/\t\t\t\t\t\t\t# Text mime-types\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tjavascript(1\\.[0-5])?\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | x-javascript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | jscript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | livescript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | (x-)?ecmascript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | babel\t\t\t\t\t\t# Javascript variant currently\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#   recognized as such\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t       | paperscript\t\t\t\t\t\t# Javascript variant currently\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#   recognized as such\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  \t)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | application/\t\t\t\t\t# Application mime-types\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  \t(\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(x-)?javascript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | (x-)?ecmascript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | module\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  \t)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t[\\s\"'>]\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t)",
```